# Backing up and migrating away from HFS+

Tags: hard-drive, backup, hfs+

I would like to back up an old hard drive from a MacBook. It uses HFS+. I currently don't have a Mac system available, but if necessary, I can borrow one. I just used rsync to copy the whole drive to a NAS, which uses btrfs. Now, after doing my homework ([.HFS+ Private Directory Data?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31734/hfs-private-directory-data)) I'm uncertain whether I'm doing things correctly.

From my understanding, HFS+ stores the file in the `.HFS+ Private*` directories if you store a file in multiple places. The actual file gets placed in one of HFS+ hidden directories, and only aliases pointing to it are used throughout the rest of the file system.

1. Can I somehow extract all files correctly from a copy made from an HFS+ drive without using a Mac?
2. Could the presence of empty folders in a copy of an HFS+ formatted
   drive, when accessed on a system using the Btrfs file system, be due to
   the Btrfs system's inability to correctly interpret the `.HFS+ Private*` directories of HFS+?
3. If I can't extract these files without a Mac, can I copy them back to an external drive to read them on macOS?